# How to make org-verbatim face include '

Tags: org-mode

Org-mode has a face `org-verbatim`. But it does not support `'` at begin or end. (same for `=`)
I use `\equal{}` to replace `=` in org-verbatim highlighted string.
But I don't know how to replace `'`.
Does anybody knows that?

Update:
here is the minimal example:

```
=$ put 'string'=
=$ put "string"=
```

Comment: What is your exact use-case. Can you give a minimal example? Do you want these replacements to work for export?

Comment: @Tobias I updated question by adding a minimal usage example.

Comment: Have you seen http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13820/inline-verbatim-and-code-with-quotes-in-org-mode