# Italic paragraphs in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Does simple markup, such as italic, work for whole paragraphs or only for parts of the line?  For example:

> /first italic paragraph
>
> second italic paragraph/

If not - what would be a correct way to do that?

Comment: AFAIK, the intent of markup is to highlight a specific portion of text from a paragraph - like highlight a particular word(s) and not entire paragraphs.  That said, if you don't mind you can insert a slash in the beginning and end of each line (using a macro) and that will give you an entire paragraph whose lines are italic. Should you copy the text elsewhere from org mode - remember that you would have the slashes in the middle of the text.

Comment: What I needed was whole paragraphs exported as italic. In the end I decided to use LaTeX blocks for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inline verbatim and code with quotes in Org-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13820/inline-verbatim-and-code-with-quotes-in-org-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum number of newlines allowed in an Org emphasis expression is controlled by the last element in `org-emphasis-regexp-components`. As is mentioned in the docstring, you need to reload Org after changing this variable to take effect:

```el
(setf (nth 4 org-emphasis-regexp-components) 10)
(load-library "org")
```

Comment: Did not know that; thanks for the tip

Comment: Sorry for silly question, but where/how to actually set this variable?

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses Emacs macros to do what you need. Follow the steps given below.

1. Use the <kbd>F3</kbd> to start recording your macro.
2. Assuming that your point is somewhere in the first line of the
   paragraph that you wish to apply italic formatting, press `C-a`.
   This takes the cursor to the beginning of the line.
3. Type the `/` key and press `C-e` to move the cursor to the end of
   the current line and type `/` again. Notice that your line is
   already has italic formatting applied in org-mode.
4. Move your point to the next line and press `C-a`.
5. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> to stop recording your macro.
6. Assuming you will re-use this macro, let us give this macro a name
   and save it for future use. Use the command `M-x
   name-last-kbd-macro` and give your macro a name. For example:
   *para_italic*.
7. Select (`C-spc`) the paragraph (only one paragraph) at a time and
   use the command `M-x apply-macro-to-region-lines`

To learn more about using keyboard macros, you can refer,

1. [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros)
2. YouTube [videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=emacs+macros) on Emacs macros. I'm following Mike Zamansky. His videos are good.