# How to use italic in quoted text in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Let us say I have the following code in an org file that I want to export to LaTeX and pdf.

```
#+BEGIN_QUOTE
  These kinds of models show that coalition building might be important.\\
  [[citep:Pamp2015][Page 15]]
#+END_QUOTE
```

How can I put every text quote in italics?

Comment: Maybe use [emphasis](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27892/italic-paragraphs-in-org-mode)?

Comment: Not too easy to implement. Maybe a better way is to change it after exporting in LaTeX.