# Org-mode markup between square brackets

Tags: org-mode, markup

My question concerns org-mode. I'm trying to add the characters `[` and `]` to the `org-emphasis-regexp-components` in order to mark up words between square brackets.  So I get for example the following effect:

`[/bla bla/]` → [*/bla bla/*]

I also want to export it to LaTeX.

I've already tried the solutions described bellow, but without success:

[Inline verbatim and code with quotes in Org-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13820/inline-verbatim-and-code-with-quotes-in-org-mode)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218238/how-to-make-part-of-a-word-bold-in-org-mode

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169333/how-can-i-emphasize-or-verbatim-quote-a-comma-in-org-mode

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.  I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: This morning, having had some rest, I did some more tests to find out what's going wrong. I got the markup working inside square brackets only in alliance with the "part of a word" markup as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218238/how-to-make-part-of-a-word-bold-in-org-mode). In other words, when I simply add the characters `[` and `]` to the `org-emphasis-regexp-components` code it doesn't work (actually all markup features go crazy). But when I add `[` and `]` plus `[:alpha:]` it works perfectly, displayed on screen as well as on LaTeX export. Why?

Comment: Maybe it's related to the fact that `[` and `]` are used in org to delimit links?

Comment: The org-emphasis-regexp-components variable consists of multiple parts. Presumably you're adding `[` to pre and `]` to post. Where are you putting `[:alpha:]`?

Comment: @glucas Yes, I'm adding the brackets exactly as you presume. As for the `[:alpha:]`, I'm puting it both to pre and post markup characters. I didn't try other combinations. As I said, it works, but it's a little annoying, so I enable the feature only for some specific export jobs, otherwise I just keep the default settings. That's all until now.

Comment: Maybe you're right… But I can't see all that conflict in using square brackets both as links delimiters and as pre and post markup characters...

Answer (score 1):

- Try this workaround using `#+MACRO:`

  ```
  #+MACRO: sbem  @@latex:[\emph{$1}]@@

  {{{sbem(blah blah)}}}
  ```

  When exported to LaTeX the macro is replaced with:

  ```
  [\emph{blah blah}]
  ```

---

> **This code was tested using:**
>   emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.10)
>   Org mode version: 9.1.2

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have in my config for this:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  ; chars for prematch
  (setcar org-emphasis-regexp-components            "     ('\"{“”\[\\") 
  ; chars for postmatch
  (setcar (nthcdr 1 org-emphasis-regexp-components) "\] -   .,!?;:''“”\")}/\\“”") 
  ; forbidden chars
  (setcar (nthcdr 2 org-emphasis-regexp-components) "    \t\r\n,\"")
  ; body
  (setcar (nthcdr 3 org-emphasis-regexp-components) ".")
  ; max newlines 
  (setcar (nthcdr 4 org-emphasis-regexp-components) 1)
  (org-set-emph-re 'org-emphasis-regexp-components org-emphasis-regexp-components))
```

Per this [stack exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13820/inline-verbatim-and-code-with-quotes-in-org-mode) discussion.