# Org mode monospaces more than it should

Tags: org-mode

Org mode lets you `monospace` text by enclosing it within `=` signs. However, I don't think the regex actually considers if it is a "starting" `=` or a "closing" `=`.

Example: `=s[=$i$=]=` renders not only the `s[` and `]` as monospace, but also the enclosed `$i$`, which is not what I want. Another example:

```
In =bar=s case, blabla, =something monospaced=
```

This monospaces  not only `bar` and `something monospaced`, but also the text within, i.e. `s case, blablabla,`. I have to insert a space between `=bar=` and the following s, but this is not something I want to do. Any help?

Comment: Check out `org-emphasis-regexp-components` and be prepared for some amount of pain. Also do a search for the variable here (e.g. [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13820/inline-verbatim-and-code-with-quotes-in-org-mode/13828#13828) might be useful). And certainly read the doc string of the variable in emacs: `C-h v org-emphasis-regexp-components RET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54673/em-dash-before-italic-in-org-export/54715#54715) for all the gory details.

The default `post` set of characters in `org-emphasis-regexp-components` is `-[:space:].,:!?;'\")}\\[` i.e. dash, the `:space:` character class, period, comma, colon, exclamation mark, question mark, semicolon, single quote, double quote, closing paren, closing brace, backslash or opening square bracket. Any of those after a closing emphasis character (`=` in your examples above) will mark the end of the emphasis region.

In your case, you want to add the dollar sign `$` to the `post` set, but you also want to add it to the `pre` set: that way, the example `=s[=$i$=]=` will work as you want it to work. For the other example, you want `s` (or perhaps any alpha char) to be in the `post` set. So in your init file, define `org-emphasis-regexp-components` as follows (and make sure that it is defined *before* you load Org mode):

```
(setq org-emphasis-regexp-components
  '("-$[:space:]('\"{"
    "-$[:alpha:][:space:].,:!?;'\")}\\["
    "[:space:]"
    "."
    1))

...

(require 'org)

...
```

This makes your examples work, but depending on your needs, it might not be enough or it might be too much: you might need to add additional characters or classes to the `pre` and/or `post` sets, but you might also find that different examples require conflicting definitions, in which case you might be stuck: this variable might be too blunt an instrument to resolve some situations.