# where are org-mode issues tracked?

Tags: org-mode

Where are org-mode issues tracked? What I mean, why I ask:

I'm having a problem with arbitrary text immediately preceding inline markup, which is the best way I can find to express the general problem underlying e.se.com posts like [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13820/5444) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28331541/915044) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1218238/915044). It's a problem I've previously encountered in [reST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText). However,

- reST has (IMHO) a reasonable, general, and clean [solution for the general problem](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#character-level-inline-markup)
- IMHO the several workarounds I've seen offered for this problem in org-mode (see comments to the above questions) are either kludges or don't WFM. (YMMV, and note I'm not here to argue this point--it's just part of the motivation for *this* question.)

At least one of the comments to the above questions suggested that this might/should be a bug on org-mode, so I thought I'd check. Assuming that Org would track their issues in the same UI with their repository (welcome to the 21st century `?-)` I searched for their repos, which are [here](https://code.orgmode.org/), and particularly found the org-mode code repo [here](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode). It's a [Gogs](https://gogs.io/) instance, and looks like a "normal" `git` front-end (e.g., bitbucket, github, gitlab) but ... no bugtracker?

I did some more websearching and I got nothing. So apologies if

- my websearch was incompetent. I searched but did not find, and am not posting this to LMGTFY.
- this question should be asked in another SE. Given that org-mode is such a major part of Emacs, I guessed this would be the place to post, but ICBW.

... but I'd like to know, how to view org-mode issues? E.g., in order to see if a bug or feature has already been proposed?

Comment: You can send bugs to either the Org mode mailing list (but that provides no help in tracking bug reports) or to the emacs bug tracker https://debbugs.gnu.org/Emacs.html. See this https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2020-05/msg00443.html and the thread around it for some details. Bottom line: I don't think you are going to be happy with the current state of affairs.

Comment: For the underlying question(s), the best answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/24540651/256171

Comment: In addition to the already mentioned mailing list, there also seems to be a relatively nice web interface to the list of org bugs [here](https://updates.orgmode.org/), via [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-issues.html).

Comment: @aplaice: thanks for those pointers! I forgot about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Note: following still "under construction" and active investigation.]*

**summary:** <del>It's a mess.</del> Org-mode issue management seems to have "grown organically."

**details:**

Thanks to commenters to my question, and going down their rabbitholes, I *might* understand--*maybe*-- how org-mode issues are currently tracked.

**TODO: ontological problems:** issue vs bug, help request vs (non-existent) 'feature request', 'update' as everything [(bugs, help requests, patches, releases)](https://updates.orgmode.org/feed/updates), etc.

**TODO:** post the org-mode list about adding an `Issues` link to [the currently-existing org-mode repo](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode).

## to propose a bug (aka, make a bug report)

There are at least 4 ways to do this, all involving email at least indirectly. One can

1. From within any Emacs buffer, do `M-x org-submit-bug-report`. This launches a new buffer to gather information to send to the Org mailing list (aka *org-ML*) @ **emacs-orgmode@gnu.org**.
2. One can send an email directly to the org-ML. If you wish to do this, please

   - provide useful feedback as described [here](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Feedback)
   - format and add helpful metadata as described [here](https://github.com/bzg/woof#basic-usage)
3. From within any Emacs buffer, do `M-x report-emacs-bug`. This launches a new buffer to gather information to send to the mailing list for Emacs bugs (aka *b.g.e-ML*) @ **bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org**. Which of course means that one can also ...
4. ... send an email directly to b.g.e-ML. Before doing that, please

   - search the [b.g.e-ML archives](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-gnu-emacs) for previous traffic regarding your problem
   - read [Reporting Bugs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bugs.html) from the Emacs manual (of course also available via `info`)

## to request a feature (aka, make an FR)

Unfortunately, AFAICS the org-mode tracking system (aka *OMTS*) ontology seems to lack this type. It *does* have a type=*help request*, which seems like a superset (FRs plus requests for assistance), or Something Completely Different. (**TODO:** investigate.) Given that "requesting help" is discussed [here](https://github.com/bzg/woof#advanced-usage), you probably (and I really am guessing here!) *don't* want to use b.g.e-ML; instead do one of

1. `M-x org-submit-bug-report` (see previous section)
2. Send email directly to org-ML (see previous section)

Either way, be sure to include the metadata discussed [here](https://github.com/bzg/woof#advanced-usage).

## to check status of a bug

current issues (which means "new"? as in not "old"?) feed: https://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=https%3A%2F%2Fupdates.orgmode.org%2Ffeed%2Fbugs&chan=y&num=10&utf=y&html=y

`RSS feed for new bugs`: https://updates.orgmode.org/feed/bugs

**TODO:** determine difference (if any) between "current issue" and "new bug"

`confirmed bugs` logged [here](https://updates.orgmode.org/#bugs)

old (but still open) issues: see https://orgmode.org/worg/org-issues.html#org43c43fd (**TODO:** needs stable/mnemonic anchor)

[org bugs via Emacs](https://debbugs.gnu.org/Emacs.html)

for completeness: check ML archives (b.g.e-ML and org-ML)

## to check status of an FR

1st, note again the lack (IIRC) of a separate FR type.

"help request" gets logged [here](https://updates.orgmode.org/#help)

for completeness: check ML archives (b.g.e and org)